# Apache: redirect to WSGI script is wrong?

Tags: python, apache, mod-rewrite, flask, mod-wsgi

I deployed a Flask application to Apache. This works, but I have added something to redirect non-www traffic to the www domain.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myapp.com
    WSGIDaemonProcess myapp python-home=/home/ubuntu/envs/myapp user=ubuntu group=ubuntu threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/myapp.wsgi
    Alias /static /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/myapp/static
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp>
        WSGIProcessGroup myapp
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This works! But, when I surf to **myapp.com/test.html** I am redirected to **www.myapp.com/myapp.wsgi/test.html** - this is not correct! I tried modifying some parameters in the file above, but currently without the desired result.

Any tips on how to solve this?

Kind regards,
B.

Comment: Don't put the rewrite rules inside of the ``Directory`` directive, put them at top level within the ``VirtualHost``.

Comment: Already tried that, but results in Apache not longer starting up...

Comment: Show the configuration when you do that and also what the error is in the Apache or system logs. When outside of the ``Directory`` directive you should not use ``RewriteBase`` for a start.

Comment: The error I got in the Apache logs was something with "caught SIGTERM" (root cause unknown).

Comment: If Apache was failing to start, as it would if you had ``RewriteBase`` outside of the ``Directory`` block, the error would have been in the system logs, not Apache error log. So, systemd logs or whatever init system was being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get things working with the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    ServerName myapp.com
    WSGIDaemonProcess myapp python-home=/home/ubuntu/envs/myapp user=ubuntu group=ubuntu threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/myapp.wsgi
    Alias /static /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp/myapp/static
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/apps/myapp>
        WSGIProcessGroup myapp
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```